# Hyphen within variable names (Proteins and Amino acids)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, protein

I have to Amino acids as variable-names within LaTeX. So far I am using (and found out):

```
\documentclass{a4paper}{article}
\newcommand\dTRP{\mathit{d-TRP}}
\begin{document}
    $[\dTRP] = 3$ (Ignore the missing units :-) - MWE )
\end{document}
```

The hyphen between "d" and "TRP" is just too long and seems to contain small spaces between "d" and "TRP" which is not very appealing to me and I suppose that I didn't do it the genuine way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `\textit` instead of `\mathit`.

With `\mathit`, the tex engine interprets the groups of characters as "words" (compare, for example the output of `$TRP$` and `$\mathit{TRP}$`), but non-letter characters are still denoting the mathematical symbol. In particular, here, the hyphen is a minus. The glyph is different, and the spacing is different.

On the other hand, `\textit` deals with elements of text, so words in the usual sense (so, possibly-containing hyphens).

To sum up:

- `$d-TRP$` should mean "variable d minus variable T times variable R times variable P"
- `$\mathit{d-DRP}$` should mean "variable d minus variable TRP" (and is poorly coded for that purpose)
- `$\textit{d-TRP}$` should mean "variable d-TRP"

Edit: To have `\textit` scaled normally in sub- and super-script, you should load the `amsmath` package. Thanks to David Carlisle for reminding me that, and for pointing my mistake about spacing around characters in `\mathit`.

Comment: well yes and no, the letter spacing for `\mathit` is the same as `\textit` it uses the text italic font, not math italic, so does not have the wide sidebearings and lack of ligatures. But it is the case that `-` is a minus sign. Note if using `\textit` you should load amsmath otherwise it won't get smaller in subscripts.

Comment: thank you very much. I will accept your answer in 3 Minutes (Forum rules...) :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you indeed for the mention of `amsmath`, I added it. Your point about the spacing surprises me more, though: do you mean that `\mathit` is really designed for word-like variables, as long as they contain no punctuation mark?

Comment: @T.Verron yes essentially. Although "design" is perhaps putting it too strong, it does what `\it` does in plain TeX in math mode, just as `\mathrm` does what `\rm` does. In both cases they use a text font but in a math setting. Unlike the `\mathnormal` (`\mit` in plain Tex) which is math italic.